# Mysql DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) , Как это работает?

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь в базу занести дату с интервалом в 1 день,использую следующий запрос

```
  <?php 
  $student = $_GET["student"];
  $bookName =  $_POST["bookName"];
  $serialNum =  $_POST["serial_num"];

  $addQuery = "INSERT INTO book_week (student_id, book_name, serial_num, date_expiration) VALUES ('{$student}' , '{$bookName}', '{$serialNum}', '{$dateExpiration}' , 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)'";
  $addResult = mysqli_query($connection, $addQuery);
  }
```

Но код не работает

Помогите пожалуйста исправить код.

Comment: А в чем именно проявляется "не работает"?

Comment: ух,оформил нечаянно на русский ресурс.... Я вот и не понимаю,просто база сбой даёт,До этого использовал без  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) а просто ставил число,и всё получалось,но только в базе вместо значения DATE стояло значение INT

Comment: Наверное не стоит `DATE_ADD()` в одиночных кавычках делать. Без них вообще. Оно должно срабатывать как MySQL функция.

Comment: На всякий случай - ты к базе подключился перед выполнением запроса?

Comment: Да подключён без функции со значением INT всё работает. Без ковычек тоже пробовал , не получается

Comment: так без кавычек может в другом месте беда, выведите на экран `$addQuery` и выполните полученный запрос напрямую в mysql, тогда покажет что ему не нравится (у вас может кавычки где-нибудь в переменных спрятались). И вместо `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` можно использовать `NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`. И почему`now()`? Почему не `utc_timestamp()`? Хотя раз с int работает - может как-то не так кавычки убираете? Приведите пример полученного `$addQuery` (т.е. например `var_dump($addQuery)`)

Answer (score 2):

У вас количество полей в insert не совпадает с количеством значений. И так же используется `{$dateExpiration}`, которая нигде не объявлена. И конечно, функцию не надо заключать в кавычки. И закрывающую круглую скобку для values забывать не стоит. Видимо должно быть так:

```
$addQuery = "INSERT INTO book_week (student_id, book_name, serial_num, date_expiration) VALUES ('{$student}' , '{$bookName}', '{$serialNum}',  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))";
```